# Why can't I find max number in a file like this?

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

I'm quite new to python, though I have a lot of experience with bash. I have a file that consists of a single column of numbers, and I would like to find the largest number in the list. I tried to do so with the following code:

```
i = 0
with open('jan14.nSets.txt','r') as data:
    for num in data:
        if num > i:
            i = num
print(i)
```

where jan14.nSets.txt is the following:

```
12
80
46
51
0
64
37
9
270
23
132
133
16
6
18
23
32
75
2
9
6
74
44
41
56
17
9
4
8
5
3
27
1
3
42
23
58
118
100
185
85
63
220
38
163
27
198
```

Rather than 270, I receive 9 as an output, and I do not understand why this is the case. I know that there are builtins for this, but I would like to know why this doesn't work to help me understand the language. I am using python2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`num` is a *string*, not a number. Turn it into an integer first using [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):

```
num = int(num)
```

You are comparing text, so it is ordered *lexicographically*, `'9' > '80'` because the ASCII character `'9'` has a higher codepoint than `'8'`:

```
>>> '9' > '80'
True
```

After the `'9'` line, all other lines either have an initial digit that is smaller than `'9'`, or the line is equal.

You could use the [`max()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) instead, provided you first use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to turn all lines into integers:

```
with open('jan14.nSets.txt','r') as data:
    i = max(map(int, data))
```

or use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) (in Python 2, more memory efficient than `map()`):

```
with open('jan14.nSets.txt','r') as data:
    i = max(int(num) for num in data)
```

Both pull in all lines from `data`, map the lines to integers, and determine the maximum value from those.

Comment: Thank you! I still don't understand I was getting 9 from my original implementation though

Comment: @user3757134: it is the same principle that sorts 'zero' after 'effort'; `z` is 'greater than' `e`, the rest of the word doesn't come into play when sorting.

Comment: @user3757134 "9" is alphabetically bigger then "270". And for text, the comparison of values is alphabetical.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. This was so helpful